# How to programmatically extend a Pipe in Revit

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I have a very particular circumstance in which I need to be able to extend the length of a pipe by a particular magnitude.   I've tried various methods - none of which work.  They include:

```
Pipe.Location.Move(XYZ fVector);       //This moves a Pipe element by the specified vector    
XYZ.Add(XYZ source);                   //I have no idea what this does, but it didn't move my XYZ variable that was my pipe end point
```

...And I know there's more things I've tried, but I can't recall them at the moment.  I've searched online and have come up empty-handed as well.  If anyone knows of a good way to extend a Pipe's length by any means, it would be a monumental help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can very easily set the pipe start and end points simply by assigning a geometry curve to its `Location` property.

Look at my series of posts on creating a rolling offset:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/01/final-rolling-offset-using-pipecreate.html

It tests and demonstrates all kinds of ways to define pipe start and end points, fitting locations, and the connections between them.

I am not saying it is exhaustive, but it will certainly provide all you need to answer your question.

Comment: We figured this out: 

```LocationCurve pLocCurve = pPipe.Location as LocationCurve;
pLocCurve.Curve = Line.CreateBound(pStart, pEnd);```

Comment: exactly what i meant. thank you for the confirmation! i would actually have thought you would have to say `pipe.Location.Curve = Line.CreateBound...` to avoid making a copy of the property in `pLocCurve`...